# Unicode replacement characters for text matching

Tags: unicode, special-characters

I have some fun with unicode text sources (all correct encodet) and I want to match names. The classic problem, one source comes correctly, an other has more flatten names:

"Elbląg" vs. "Elblag" (see the character a)

How can I "flatten" ą, á, â or à to a for better matching? Are there unicode to ascii- matching tables?

Comment: Which programming language? If C/C++, What libraries you can use?

Comment: I use python for this task ... I think I need large unicode character assignment table - so I have to convert it if it comes from another source.

Comment: python 2.x - I could switch to 3.x if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'Elbląg').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'Elblag'
```

Comment: Thanx - all the polish names are matching!

Comment: Be aware that not all accented Latin letters have an NFKD decomposition as ASCII letter + combining mark.  For example, 'ø' does not decompose.